# Grouping and then filtering data

Tags: r, filter, grouping

I have the following df:

```
  A B C D E F
1 8 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 1 5 7 1 2
3 1 0 0 2 1 0
4 6 0 0 0 0 2
```

I want to first group the data into 2 groups, each with 3 replicates, e.g. A:C are one group and D:F is the second group.

I then want to exclude any rows with values = 0 in at least 2 replicates/columns in either group. So I should get back the following df:

```
  A B C D E F
1 2 1 5 7 1 2
2 1 0 0 2 1 0
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your result df doesn't make sense to me.  It has two zeros in row two, columns A:C

Comment: People's use of "each", "either", "both" are often divergent from my understanding of their logical meaning.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation was:

```
> dat[ rowSums(dat[1:3]==0)<2 | rowSums(dat[4:6]==0)<2 , ]
  A B C D E F
2 2 1 5 7 1 2
3 1 0 0 2 1 0
```

This is the literal transliteration (which should be logically the same):

```
> dat[ !( rowSums(dat[1:3]==0)>=2 & rowSums(dat[4:6]==0)>=2) , ]
  A B C D E F
2 2 1 5 7 1 2
3 1 0 0 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ddf = structure(list(A = c(8L, 2L, 1L, 6L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    C = c(0L, 5L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 7L, 2L, 0L), E = c(0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L), F = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 2L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df1 = ddf[,1:3]
df2 = ddf[,4:6]

ddf[which(rowSums(df2==0)<2 & rowSums(df1==0)<2),]
  A B C D E F
2 2 1 5 7 1 2
```

Your criteria is: "I then want to exclude any rows with values = 0 in at least 2 replicates/columns in either group."
Hence only one row satisfies this criteria. The second row in your own answer ( 1 0 0 2 1 0 )
does not satisfy this criteria, since first group here has 2 zeros (1 0 0).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2 groups, you could do:

```
 N <- ncol(dat)
 indx <- Reduce(`|`,
          lapply(seq(1,N, by=3), function(i) rowSums(!dat[i:(i+2)])<2) )
 dat[indx,]
 #  A B C D E F
 #2 2 1 5 7 1 2
 #3 1 0 0 2 1 0
```